# Asymptotic correlation between sample mean and sample median

Tags: asymptotics, correlation, median

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\cdots$ are i.i.d. $N(\mu,1)$. Show that the asymptotic correlation between sample mean and sample median (after suitably centering and renormalization) is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to M.SE. Can you share your thoughts on the problem and explain what you've tried?

Comment: I have proved that sample quantiles are asymptotically normal, so is the sample median. Sample mean is asymptotically normal via CLT. The correlation coefficient between two random variables $X,Y$ can be written as a function of $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i,\sum_{i=1}^nX_i,\sum_{i=1}^nY_i,\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2,\sum_{i=1}^nY_i^2,\sum_{i=1}^nX_iY_i$. So I was trying the Delta Method. But got entirely confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obtain 
[this paper](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/papers/unpublished/meanmed.pdf), written by T.S. Ferguson, a professor at UCLA (his page is [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/)).

It derives the *joint* asymptotic distribution for the sample mean and sample median.

To be specific, let $\hat X_n$ be the sample mean and $\mu$ the population mean, $Y_n$ be the sample median and $\mathbb v$ the population median. Let $f()$ be the probability density of the random variables involved ($X$) Let $\sigma^2$ be the variance. Then Ferguson proves that

$$\sqrt n\Big [\left (\begin{matrix} \hat X_n \\ Y_n \end{matrix}\right) - \left (\begin{matrix} \mu \\ \mathbb v \end{matrix}\right)\Big ] \rightarrow_{\mathbf L}\; N\Big [\left (\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right) , \Sigma \Big]$$

$$ \Sigma = \left (\begin{matrix} \sigma^2 & E\left(|X-\mathbb v|\right)\left[2f(\mathbb v)\right]^{-1} \\ E\left(|X-\mathbb v|\right)\left[2f(\mathbb v)\right]^{-1} & \left[2f(\mathbb v)\right]^{-2} \end{matrix}\right)$$

Then the asymptotic correlation of this centered and normalized quantity is (abusing notation as usual)

$$\rho_{A}(\hat X_n,\, Y_n) = \frac {\text {Cov} (\hat X_n,\, Y_n)}{\sqrt {\text{Var}(\hat X_n)\text{Var}(Y_n)}} =  \frac {E\left(|X-\mathbb v|\right)\left[2f(\mathbb v)\right]^{-1}}{\sigma\left[2f(\mathbb v)\right]^{-1}} = \frac {E\left(|X-\mathbb v|\right)}{\sigma}$$

In your case, $\sigma = 1$ so we end up with

$$\rho_{A}(\hat X_n,\, Y_n) = E\left(|X-\mathbb v|\right)$$

In your case, the population follows the normal with unitary variance, so the random variable  $Z= X-\mathbb v$ is $N(0,1)$.
Then its absolute value follows the (standard) [*half normal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) distribution, whose expected value is 
$$ E(|Z|) =\sigma\sqrt {\frac{2}{\pi}} = \sqrt {\frac{2}{\pi}}$$
since here $\sigma =1$.
So 
$$\rho_{A}(\hat X_n,\, Y_n) = \sqrt {\frac{2}{\pi}}$$

*Added note*: It can be seen that the result does not depend on $\sigma =1$ since $\sigma$ cancels out from nominator and denominator.